# Grails Plugins installation fails from remote grails repositories

Tags: grails, maven-plugin, grails-plugin, ggts

Since a couple of days I cannot install any Grails plugin anymore if it is not already existing locally in the local maven repositories or ivy-cache.

E.g. for the plugin called "plugin-config" when trying to install I get the message:

```
module not found: org.grails.plugins#plugin-config;0.2.0

[..]

==== grailsCentral: tried
  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-plugin-config/tags/RELEASE_0.2.0/plugin-config-0.2.0.pom
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#plugin-config;0.2.0!plugin-config.zip:
  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-plugin-config/tags/RELEASE_0.2.0/grails-plugin-config-0.2.0.zip

[..]
```

(Entering the path in a web browser the zip and pom files both are getting found.)

This happens if I set a dependecy in BuildConfig.groovy like this:

```
compile ":plugin-config:0.2.0"
```

It also happens if I try to install the plugin using the plugin manager.

The plugins in local maven repository or in ivy-cache are getting installed. Is it possible that there is a connection issue with GGTS? Is there any way to download plugins manually?

I'm using:

- GGTS Version: 3.6.3.SR1, Build Id: 201501121239, Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)
- Groovy 2.1
- Grails 2.2.4